# Sorting an array of categories and subcategories

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Suppose we have and array of objects where each object represents a category or a subcategory, like this one:

```
var data = [
    {type: "parent-category", order: 1, categoryId: 1},
    {type: "parent-category", order: 2, categoryId: 2},
    {type: "child-category", order: 1, categoryId: 3, parentCategoryId: 1},
    {type: "child-category", order: 2, categoryId: 4, parentCategoryId: 1},
    {type: "child-category", order: 2, categoryId: 5, parentCategoryId: 2},
    {type: "child-category", order: 1, categoryId: 6, parentCategoryId: 2}
];
```

This array represent an example with two categories, where each one of they also have two subcategories.

Now, I'm facing with the problem of sort this array on some custom way. As you can note, the `order` attribute inside each object is related to the position (or ordering) of the object inside his level of hierarchy. And the relation between categories and subcategories is defined by the atributte `parentCategoryId`.

The expected sorting I need using as example the previous array of data should be this one:

```
var data = [
    {type: "parent-category", order: 1, categoryId: 1},
    {type: "child-category", order: 1, categoryId: 3, parentCategoryId: 1},
    {type: "child-category", order: 2, categoryId: 4, parentCategoryId: 1},
    {type: "parent-category", order: 2, categoryId: 2},
    {type: "child-category", order: 1, categoryId: 6, parentCategoryId: 2},
    {type: "child-category", order: 2, categoryId: 5, parentCategoryId: 2}   
];
```

My current approach to solve this problem is based on creating a map to numbers, analyzing the values of the attributes with the following conditions:

- For an object that has the type **parent-category** we assign the value of `categoryId * 1000`.
- For an object that has the class **child-category** we assign the value of `(parentCategoryId * 1000) + order`

This logic is shown on the next sort implementation:

```js
let data = [
    {type: "parent-category", order: 1, categoryId: 1},
    {type: "parent-category", order: 2, categoryId: 2},
    {type: "child-category", order: 1, categoryId: 3, parentCategoryId: 1},
    {type: "child-category", order: 2, categoryId: 4, parentCategoryId: 1},
    {type: "child-category", order: 2, categoryId: 5, parentCategoryId: 2},
    {type: "child-category", order: 1, categoryId: 6, parentCategoryId: 2}
];

let orderedData = data.sort((a, b) =>
{
    var aCat = (a.type == "parent-category") ? a.categoryId : a.parentCategoryId;
    var aOrder = (a.type == "parent-category") ? 0 : a.order;
    var bCat = (b.type == "parent-category") ? b.categoryId : b.parentCategoryId;
    var bOrder = (b.type == "parent-category") ? 0 : b.order;

    return (aCat * 1000 + aOrder) - (bCat * 1000 + bOrder);
});

console.log(orderedData);
```

However, and ignoring the fact that the previous implementation works, my question is if there exists a better approach or alternative to solve this problem. I don't like the idea of depend on the mapping to numbers, because, for example, the previous implementation introduces a limitation on the numbers of subcategories (`999` in this case) I can sort correctly under each category. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple performant solution using Array#filter Array#sort and Array#map

```js
var data=[{type:"parent-category",order:1,categoryId:1},{type:"parent-category",order:2,categoryId:2},{type:"child-category",order:1,categoryId:3,parentCategoryId:1},{type:"child-category",order:2,categoryId:4,parentCategoryId:1},{type:"child-category",order:2,categoryId:5,parentCategoryId:2},{type:"child-category",order:1,categoryId:6,parentCategoryId:2}]

let res = data
  .filter(({type}) => type === "parent-category")
  .sort((a,b) => a.order - b.order)
  .reduce((acc, curr) =>{
    const children = data
      .filter(({parentCategoryId}) => parentCategoryId === curr.categoryId)
      .sort((a,b) => a.order - b.order);

    acc.push(curr, ...children);
    return acc;
  }, []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This works also, thanks! I will give a better review tomorrow.

Comment: Now, it is much better, I like this one. Just check that the current result has two arrays and I need only one.

Comment: Ok, it is good now, I made some edits to move the `reduce()` in place of the `map()` making simplifications on the code, I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 3):

If performance is not an issue, I'd prefer using a more step-by-step way:

```js
/* ORIGINAL DATA */
const data = [
    {type: "parent-category", order: 1, categoryId: 1},
    {type: "parent-category", order: 2, categoryId: 2},
    {type: "child-category", order: 1, categoryId: 3, parentCategoryId: 1},
    {type: "child-category", order: 2, categoryId: 4, parentCategoryId: 1},
    {type: "child-category", order: 2, categoryId: 5, parentCategoryId: 2},
    {type: "child-category", order: 1, categoryId: 6, parentCategoryId: 2}
];


const sorted = [];
const byOrder = (a, b) => a.order - b.order;

// Get and sort parents first
const parents = data.filter(obj => obj.type === 'parent-category');
parents.sort(byOrder);

// Push to resulting array by parent order
parents.forEach(obj => {
  sorted.push(obj);
  
  // Get and sort corresponding children objs
  const children = data.filter(o => o.parentCategoryId === obj.categoryId);
  children.sort(byOrder);
  
  // Push the objs into resulting array together
  sorted.push.apply(sorted, children);
});


console.log(sorted);
```

This approach involves more steps, but is straightforward and can be easily understood compared to your complex sorting logic.

Using external libraries for only one function is overkill.

Comment: Good approach +1, thank you! However, I'm going to wait a little more just in case another answer comes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @kemicofa answer. Just changed it to support more than two levels

```
function iterative(categories, parentCategory, level = 0) {
  return categories
    .filter((category) => parentCategory ? category.parent === parentCategory : !category.parent)
    .map(category => {
       category.level = level;
       return category;
    })
    .sort((a,b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
    .reduce((acc, curr) =>{
      const children = iterative(categories, curr.id, level+1)

      acc.push(curr, ...children);
      return acc;
    }, [])
  ;
}
```

Comment: Seems like a nice generalization, could you provide a sample of input, i.e, a sample of `categories` argument to test it?

Answer (score 0):

**For easy way, use [lodash#orderBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#orderBy)**

---

If you don't prefer *lodash*, you can define your own specific function in `sort`

I have not fully understand your sorting criteria, but, for example,

```
function sort_categories(cat1,cat2) {
  if (cat1["order"] < cat2["order"])
    return -1;
  if (cat1["order"] > cat2["order"])
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

data.sort(sort_categories);
```

will simply sort by orders.

For details about return values, take a [look at here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> If compareFunction is supplied, all non-undefined array elements are
>   sorted according to the return value of the compare function (all
>   undefined elements are sorted to the end of the array, with no call to
>   compareFunction). If a and b are two elements being compared, then:
>
> - If compareFunction(a, b) is less than 0, sort a to an index lower than b (i.e. a comes first).
> - If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different
>     elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this
>     behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating
>     back to at least 2003) respect this.
> - If compareFunction(a, b) is greater than 0, sort b to an index lower than a (i.e. b comes first).
> - compareFunction(a, b) must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments. If
>     inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined.

Comment: I can't figure out an easy way of doing the sort with `orderBy`. You should note that categories have their order specified and subcategories too, but subcategories have to go (sorted) right after his parent category.

Answer (score 0):

This will work. You sort your categoryId first and then do your math by running the forEach function.

```js
var data = [
    {type: "parent-category", order: 1, categoryId: 1},
    {type: "parent-category", order: 2, categoryId: 2},
    {type: "child-category", order: 1, categoryId: 3, parentCategoryId: 1},
    {type: "child-category", order: 2, categoryId: 4, parentCategoryId: 1},
    {type: "child-category", order: 2, categoryId: 5, parentCategoryId: 2},
    {type: "child-category", order: 1, categoryId: 6, parentCategoryId: 2}
];

data.sort( function(a, b){
    return a.categoryId - b.categoryId;
}).forEach( function(itm){  
    itm.categoryId = itm.categoryId * 1000;
    if( itm.parentCategoryId){
        itm.parentCategoryId = itm.parentCategoryId * 1000 + itm.order
    }
});

console.log(data);
```

Or in ES6 fashion...

```
let orderedData = data.sort( (a, b) => {
       return a.categoryId - b.categoryId;
    }).forEach( itm => {
        itm.categoryId = itm.categoryId * 1000;
        if( itm.parentCategoryId){
            itm.parentCategoryId = itm.parentCategoryId * 1000 + itm.order
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please, check the expected output, this is not working as expected. Also, I don't want to change the values of the attributes, I just want to apply a custom order on the array of objects.