# How order an array by parent elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

The example is simple, but it will help me solve a complex problem, for a data table created with angular and material, which receives an array.
I receive an array of objects, which I want to organize by parentage , as the following example, which I represent in a simple way so as not to entangle the question with complex data.

I receive the data as array1:

```
array1 = [
  {id:1, parent_id:0, data:'txt'},
  {id:2, parent_id:0, data:'txt'},
  {id:3, parent_id:1, data:'txt'},
  {id:4, parent_id:1, data:'txt'},
  {id:5, parent_id:0, data:'txt'},
  {id:6, parent_id:0, data:'txt'},
  {id:7, parent_id:5, data:'txt'},
];
```

and I want to organize it as array2.

```
array2 = [
  {id:1, parent_id:0, data:'txt'},
  {id:3, parent_id:1, data:'txt'},
  {id:4, parent_id:1, data:'txt'},
  {id:2, parent_id:0, data:'txt'},
  {id:5, parent_id:0, data:'txt'},
  {id:7, parent_id:5, data:'txt'},
  {id:6, parent_id:0, data:'txt'},
];
```

Comment: What's the logic by which the second array is sorted?

Comment: How array2 is different from array1 ? I mean how exactly you want to organize ?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Are you familiar with the notions of depth-first-search and/or topological sort?

Comment: For everyone asking for clarification on how exactly `array2` was formed, draw the implied tree (the `parent_id` field is the id of the parent), then do a depth-first search and you get exactly `array2`.

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#sortBy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have one possible solution using firstly [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the objects without parents (i.e objects where `parent_id:0`) and then sort they using the `id` property. After this, we use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the list of children for each of the previous objects, sort those childrens and put they inmediatly after the his parent. However, this is not an efficient solution, maybe there are betters.

```js
const array1 = [
  {id:1, parent_id:0, data:'txt'},
  {id:2, parent_id:0, data:'txt'},
  {id:3, parent_id:1, data:'txt'},
  {id:4, parent_id:1, data:'txt'},
  {id:5, parent_id:0, data:'txt'},
  {id:6, parent_id:0, data:'txt'},
  {id:7, parent_id:5, data:'txt'},
];

let res = array1
    .filter(({parent_id}) => parent_id === 0)
    .sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)
    .reduce((acc, curr) =>
    {
        const children = array1
            .filter(({parent_id}) => parent_id === curr.id)
            .sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);

        return [...acc, curr, ...children];
    }, []);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

The solution comes from a similar question I have made some time ago, you can also check other answers there, and my first approach (better in performance, but not generic, it had some limitations as explained there) to address a problem like this: [Sorting an array of categories and subcategories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000633/sorting-an-array-of-categories-and-subcategories)